# Responsive CSS Grid layout with position: fixed

Tags: css, html, css-grid

I'm building a responsive template with CSS Grid Layout (still learning) and thanks to a few of you on here, I've got most of it working.

- mobile (max-width: 767px)

  - everything should appear on its own row
- tablet (min-width: 768px)

  - nav is on the first row
  - aside and main on the second
- desktop (min-width: 992px)

  - same as tablet but with 10% of spacing horizontally
- xl desktop (min-width: 1920px)

  - same as desktop but has a max-width of 1920px

The thing is I'm using a `header` tag to color the spacing to the left and right of the `nav`. Whether I use a header or a div, it doesn't seem right having an empty container just for coloring the empty space.
Is there a way of doing this in a way that lets me apply `position: fixed` on the entire top section?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

header,
nav {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

nav span {
  margin-right: auto;
}

header {
  display: none;
}

aside {
  background: lightgreen;
}

main {
  background: pink;
}


/* mobile  */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
  nav,
  aside,
  main {
    grid-column: 1 / 1;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
}


/* tablets */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 275px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  nav {
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
    grid-row: 1;
    height: 50px;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  aside {
    grid-column: 1;
  }
  main {
    grid-column: 2;
  }
  nav,
  aside,
  main {
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
}


/* desktops */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 10% 275px 1fr 10%;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  header {
    display: block;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  nav {
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  aside {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
  }
  main {
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
  }
}


/* xl desktops */

@media (min-width: 1920px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(auto, 300px) minmax(auto, 1620px) 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<nav>
  <span>Logo</span>
  <a href="#">login</a>
</nav>
<aside>aside</aside>
<main>main</main>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/90kotz8d/1/

Comment: You're asking two questions: one about spacing and another about media queries. It's normally better to focus on one question at a time.

Comment: With regard to media queries, here you go: [Common breakpoints for media queries on a responsive site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8564752/3597276)

Comment: I've edited the question and will create a another one for media queris. Thanks

Comment: The link I posted may answer your question about media queries.

Comment: What's the tag you're using to creating spacing? The `header` on wider screens?

Comment: the header tag with grid-column and grid-template-columns

Comment: Could you post a comment saying why my previous answer is not suitable for you ? It will be easier to help you this way

Comment: Are you trying to create spacing from the top of the page? Where is it that you are conflicted with using a tag just for spacing?

Comment: the property grid not full support to many browsers

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your intent, you are not really using header for spacing, you are really using it to get the blue background to cover all the space.

Since you seem also wanting the logo and login to vertically align with the boundaries, I don't think that there is any posible solution to do this with the nav.

So, the only solution that I could find involves using a pseudo element. At least this is more semantic.  I got rid of the media queries, since now they don't play a role here:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 10% 275px 1fr 10%;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.container::after {
    content: "";
    background-color: blue;
    grid-column: 1 / 5;
    grid-row: 1;
    z-index: -1;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}


nav {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

nav span {
  margin-right: auto;
}

header {
  display: none;
}

aside {
  background: lightgreen;
}

main {
  background: pink;
}
nav {
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  aside {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
  }
  main {
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<nav>
  <span>Logo</span>
  <a href="#">login</a>
</nav>
<aside>aside</aside>
<main>main</main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

From what I can see, you might need to add a rule saying it is `display: block;` before you can add the `position: fixed` rule, because I am pretty sure `<header>`s are inline elements.

You could also try and add media queries, linking to different stylesheets, that display different tables, using the `display: tableRow;`, `tableCell` and `table` values.

Hope this works

Comment: `<header>` is a block level element.

Answer (score 4):

I guess, this is something, what you want. I have used `grid-column: 1 / 8;` in the `@media (min-width: 992px)` and added manual padding on both sides. I hope, without this solution, till now no more options you are having without using extra `<div>`, `<header>` or any other containers.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

header,
nav {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

nav span {
  margin-right: auto;
}

header {
  display: none;
}

aside {
  background: lightgreen;
}

main {
  background: pink;
}

/* mobile  */


@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
  
  nav,
  aside,
  main {
    grid-column: 1 / 1;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
}


/* tablets */


@media (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 275px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  
  nav {
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
    grid-row: 1;
    height: 50px;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  
  aside {
    grid-column: 1;
  }
  
  main {
    grid-column: 2;
  }
  
  nav,
  aside,
  main {
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
}


/* desktops */


@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 10% 275px 1fr 10%;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  
  nav {
    grid-column: 1 / 8;
    grid-row: 1;
    padding-right: 11.3vw;
    padding-left: 11.3vw;
  }
  
  aside {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
  }
  
  main {
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
  }
}


/* xl desktops */


@media (min-width: 1920px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(auto, 300px) minmax(auto, 1620px) 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span>Logo</span>
  <a href="#">login</a>
</nav>
<aside>aside</aside>
<main>main</main>
```